# How to get the hidden fields from any entity in TCC

Tags: tcc, taleo, taleo-connect-client

I'm looking for these two fields: JobInformation,DescriptionExternalHTML and JobInformation,DescriptionInternalHTML. In which Recruiting module and entity can I find these fields?

I have searched for these fields JobInformation,DescriptionExternalHTML and JobInformation,DescriptionInternalHTML in Recruiting(14 A) module under the requisition entity.

Comment: [TCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) is a compiler ([Tiny C Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler)). Is this about that ***[Taleo Connect Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/taleo-connect-client)*** (or ***Taleo Client Connect***?) thingy (whatever it is)?

Comment: This should probably be retagged.